# How to implement thread timeout in J2ME?

Tags: java, networking, mobile, timeout, java-me

I am using `Connector` in J2ME and found that sometimes it take a very long time to send a request, and sometime it may halt the whole process.
So I try to put code related to `Connector` in a thread and try to set timeout to the thread. But I found out that it's very difficult to do this in J2ME because there's no `join(timeout)` in J2ME.
Is there any way to do this? Or any better way to deal with network connection in J2ME?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How did you integrate timeout ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a combination of 3 mechanisms:

- `Connector.open()` can be used with a third parameter for timeout.
- You can call `Thread.sleep()` and `Connection.close()` from a different thread than the one you call `Connector.open()` in.
- You can call `Thread.sleep()` and `Thread.interrupt()` from a different thread than the one you call `Connector.open()` in.

On some badly implemented MIDP runtimes, `Connection.close()` can block if the connection is busy. You need to test this thoroughly on the handsets you plan to support.

`Thread.interrupt()` can leave the MIDP runtime (and the underlying handset operating system) with orphaned resources so only use it as a last resort.